# Resharper destroys metadata viewer formatting

Tags: resharper, metadata

Can I somehow get the vanilla metadata viewer with Resharper? The closest I get is Resharper's metadata viewer.

Before Resharper:
[image]

After Resharper:
[image]

And if I use word wrapping on Resharper's window, I get this:
[image]

Comment: *squints some* -_-. I see metadata markup in the Resharper code, but only see a bunch of comments in the initial code - you're probably lucky it generates the proper stuff reasonably well, given the input, in my questionable opinion.

Comment: No luck is involved, visual studio always generates such comments for BCL classes

Comment: Could you please clarify what you find wrong with ReSharper output?

Comment: The original metadata output is very readable and comfortable. XML doc tags are interperted and used to format the documentation. In addition, it is always wrapped to fit within the screen. With resharper, the tags are ignored and the xml documentation appears just the way it is, with very long lines that I have to scroll. For me, it's basically unusable. I'm not asking Resharper to do all the hard parsing work - just let me use the original...

Comment: I see. I would switch off xml-doc generation altogether, and then use ReSharper's quick doc feature (ReSharper/Edit/Show quick doc) to see nicely formatted documentation when needed.

Comment: Thanks, it's a a very nice feature - didn't know about it. However I still don't get a property / event / public method listing for classes and interfaces

Comment: I hate the resharper metadata viewer. So annoying. Can't you just turn it off and go back to the VS viewer? Ohad, maybe start a bounty on this question?

Comment: @joniba - I don't believe a bounty would help as it's not a matter of knowledge, rather a missing feature in Resharper (Ilya Ryzhenkov works there)